# Regex pattern to find Integers in every line of the string

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern here which finds the integers after a comma.

The problem I have is that my return value is in new lines, so the pattern only works on the new line. How do I fix this? I want it to find the pattern in every line.

All help is appreciated:

```
url = new URL("https://test.com");
con = url.openConnection();
is = con.getInputStream();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String responseData = line;
    System.out.println(responseData);
}

pattern = "(?<=,)\\d+";
pr = Pattern.compile(pattern);
match = pr.matcher(responseData); // String responseData

System.out.println();

while (match.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + match.group());
}
```

Here is the response returned as a string:

```
test.test.test.test.test-test,0,0,0
test.test.test.test.test-test,2,0,0
test.test.test.test.test-test,0,0,3
```

Here is the printout:

```
Found: 0
Found: 0
Found: 0
```

Comment: Show us sample input and expected output. You might be needing `DOT_ALL` option.. can't really say anything without sample nput and output

Comment: If it's `\n` at the end of the line, it *should* work.

Comment: @MarounMaroun It doesnt work. My code only matches the first line and not the rest.

Comment: SandeepSingh . Like @MarounMaroun says, your code should work.. Your regex is fine, I am afraid I cannnot say the same about your input string. Is it one string or multiple strings?

Comment: @TheLostMind The response is read from a bufferreader.. I updated my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with building your String, you're assigning only the last line from the `BufferedReader`:

```
responseData = line;
```

If you print `responseData` before you try to match, you'll see it's only one line, and not what you expected.

Since you're printing the buffer's content using a `System.out.println`, you *do* see the whole result, but what's getting saved to `responseData` is actually the last line.

You should use a `StringBuilder` to build the whole string:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    str.append(line);
}
responseData = str.toString();
// now responseData contains the whole String, as you expected
```

Tip: Use the debugger, it'll make you better understand your code and will help you to find bugs very faster.

Comment: My thought exactly, until I read the printout. Assuming it's copy-pasted, there are 3 0's, which mean the first line is still in resposneData. Any explanation for that?

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens I think it's a typo, the last found must be 3, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pattern.MULTILINE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) option when compiling your regex:

```
pattern = "(?<=,)\\d+";
pr = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: This flag is relevant when you're matching `^` and `$`.